# Javascript Redirect use with blockUI and setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, settimeout, redirect, jquery-blockui

I use to Javascript page use `$.blockUI` in a function and I want 3 second block this page. That's why I added to `setTimeOut` but this function called to `Redirect function` after `blockUI`. Don't working `setTimeOut` in this code or called Redirect function.

How can I do it?

```
    $.blockUI({
       message: "block message",
        css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px'
        }
    });
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 3000);
    URL.Redirect("RedirectURLfunctionName");
```

Comment: try this one: setTimeout(()=>{$.unblockUI()}, 3000);

Comment: Do you want the `Redirect` to happen before or after calling `$.unblockUI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code it will not wait for `setTimeout` timeout will only be executed after all the code in a block has finished executing.
`onUnblock` callback is invoked when all the blocking elements have been removed

```
$.blockUI({
    message: "block message",
    css: {
        border: 'none',
        padding: '15px'
    }
})

setTimeout(function () {
    $.unblockUI({
        onUnblock: function () { URL.Redirect("RedirectURLfunctionName"); }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: @Isma Thanks, Done.